# How to say that I've finished my master degree studies?

Tags: phrases

I've just finished my master studies in computer science and I'm writing a cover letter for a research internship.

How should I declare my studies background? I thought something like:

> I have a master in Computer Science...

But I don't know if there is a more proper way to say it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have recently completed your master's degree and writing a cover letter, you might want to write the following:

> I have *recently completed* a master's in Computer Science...

or using your sentence:

> I have a master's in Computer Science...

---

Please note the following:

- the [***'** s*] after *master* indicates a possessive (the degree of a master), not a plural.
- If you’re speaking of a specific degree, you should capitalise master and avoid creating a possessive: Master of Computer Science

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. So it is better to write "I have recently completed a Master of Computer Science"?

Comment: If you want to use _Master of Computer Science_, you could try "I have recently completed a Master of Computer Science degree from the University of Englsih-Stack-Exchange." Alternatively "I have recently completed a master's in Computer Science..." should suffice the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You also might consider taking another approach altogether using the present participle form of **have**, something like:

"*Having* recently completed a Master of Computer Science from XYZ University, I'm well equipped to handle a variety of issues related to the role your company is filling. Specifically, my area of expertise and concentration of study was in *xyz topic*, therefore I can offer a unique insight into the challenges you might face throughout your organization."

I thought I would give you another option which is also perfectly acceptable. The above answer was very good as well. And I also wanted to offer it in an expanded form which might help you flesh out the content of the letter. I hope it helps.